# How to generate the same EC_KEY "n" times

Tags: openssl

to generate an EC_KEY i can use the following pgm (and it works perfectly).

```
    EC_KEY *eckey = EC_KEY_new();
    EC_GROUP *ecgroup= EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp192k1);
    int set_group_status = EC_KEY_set_group(eckey,ecgroup);
    int gen_status = EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);
```

But this one will generate different EC keys each time i excute it (which is complitly normal). What i need is a pgm that generates the same EC_KEY regardless how many time I execute it, how to do this?? thnx

Answer (score 2):

As you say, generate creates a new key. If you want to reuse a key, generate it
once then **store** that key and re-use it as desired. Within one program execution (process)
this is easy, so I assume you want to reuse it in later executions of the same program,
of different program(s), or on different system(s). To do these, you need to **write out
and later read in** the key.

One storage format used by OpenSSL for most things, including ECC keys, is ASN.1 **DER**,
and the simplest functions for this all begin `i2d_` or `d2i_` which mean internal-to-DER and DER-to-internal. For EC_KEY these are `{i2d,d2i}_EC{Private,Public}Key`. The Private format actually includes the public value, but the Public format excludes the private value and thus can only be used for public operations but can safely be distributed.
These basic routines write to a memory buffer you can store someplace
retrievable, or read from a memory buffer you retrieved.

For ECC (unlike other public/private keys) there are **two ways to encode** the parameters
of the group used, usually (though imprecisely) called **the curve**. For standard curves
(like secp192k1, the one you used) ASN.1 OIDs are assigned and the serialized
form can simply use the OID; this is called "named" form. Alternatively, the parameters
(modulus for a prime underlying field or polynomial for a "binary" underlying field, curve
equation coefficients, generating or base point coordinates, order and cofactor) can be
encoded explicitly; this is called "explicit" form. **Named form is almost always best**;
it is much shorter and easier to use, for some purposes (notably SSL/TLS) OpenSSL can
only use named form, and some other systems may accept only named form. But it is not yet
the OpenSSL default, so you should `EC_GROUP_set_asn1_flag(group,OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE)`
before serializing. (It is automatically set when deserializing.)

One basic storage method is disk files. There are `{i2d,d2i}_*_fp`
functions that write to and read from a `FILE*` opened in C using `fopen()` or equivalent.
OpenSSL also has its own I/O scheme called BIO, and there are `{i2d,d2i}_*_bio`
functions that write and read a BIO, although the BIOs other than memory and files are rarely useful for keys. Or you can put the DER blob in some other storage
used by your program(s) such as a database, a file server, a web server, the "cloud", etc.

You may prefer **PEM** format. Some crypto objects commonly used and shared
such as X.509 certificates use a scheme originally designed for PEM
(although PEM itself has fallen by the wayside). This format encodes the binary DER
to base 64 with line breaks at a convenient size (usually 64 or 76 characters)
and adds a header line of the form `-----BEGIN OBJECTTYPE-----` and a trailer line
of the form `-----END OBJECTTYPE-----`. PEM format was created to allow binary data
to be handled without loss or corruption through email systems that years ago could
not handle binary data; today it still has the advantage that it can be displayed
consistently in any editor or terminal/console/whatever and can be copy-and-pasted
between files or systems without loss or corruption. OpenSSL extends the PEM
scheme to many other objects, including keys, and for many OpenSSL *commandline*
operations PEM format is at least more convenient and sometimes required.
From a program there are functions beginning `PEM_read_` and `PEM_write_`,
in this case `PEM_{read,write}_EC{Private,Public}Key` that write or read a `FILE*`,
or `PEM_{read,write}_bio_$same` that write or read a BIO.

You may also consider **generic formats and certificates**, especially if you
want to share or exchange these keys with other program(s). Most crypto systems
today need to handle multiple algorithms or at least be able to; best practice is
to use generic formats that handle all needed algorithms in a combined and consistent way.
OpenSSL implements this using the `EVP_KEY` structure and related functions; EVP* can handle an
RSA key and do RSA, a DSA or DH key and do DSA or DH, an ECC key and do ECDSA or ECDH, etc.

For private keys the generic format is **PKCS#8** [aka rfc5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208).
This basically consists of an ASN.1 structure `AlgorithmIdentifier`
which identifies the algorithm and applicable parameters plus an opaque OCTETSTRING that contains algorithm-dependent key information. The functions for this are
`{i2d,d2i}_PrivateKey` and `{i2d,d2i}_PKCS8PrivateKey{_bio,_fp}` (slightly inconsistent for "hysterical raisins")
and `PEM_{read,write}{,_bio}_PKCS8PrivateKey`.
PKCS#8 privatekeys **can be encrypted** to prevent leakage of your key if you use a storage method that doesn't itself provide good security, whereas the algorithm-specific DER forms can't be encrypted at all and the algorithm-specific PEM forms in OpenSSL support only an old and weak form of encryption.

For public keys the generic format is by a (small) part of X.509,
more conveniently available in [rfc5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1)
and expanded for algorithms like ECC in [rfc3279](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.3.5).
This format similarly has an AlgorithmIdentifier plus an opaque BITSTRING containing the algorithm-specific key.
The EVP_PKEY i2d/d2i and PEM functions for this are `*PUBKEY*`.
There are also convenience functions that use the generic external format with specific internal types,
which for ECC are `*EC_PUBKEY*`.

For many schemes using public-key crypto, including ECC, public keys are distributed,
stored and used in the form of **X.509** certificates, which contain the public keys in the
format described just above, combined with the subject name(s) and other relevant attributes,
cryptographically signed by a Certificate Authority. OpenSSL has (many) functions
for X.509 certificates and related things like CRLs, CSRs, and OCSP. But that's a bigger question.

Most of these routines have man pages on any Unix system with OpenSSL installed,
or online at <strike>https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/</strike> moved 2017 to https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/ . There are gaps here and there,
but you can usually infer the missing bits by looking at similar and related functions.

Comment: My comment was so long so i post it as an answer @dave_thompson_085

Comment: Your post is incredibly helpful. In fact, it is more helpful than everything I ever read on the OpenSSL wiki. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Multisync: you're welcome, and thanks for reminding me of an out-of-date link